# Renaming a file in google sheet to previous month name using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a backup sheet of  a google sheet file and its name should be "previous month name + year". Backup file is created, renaming the file is not happening.

```
function Copy() {
var sss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT'); 
var range = ss.getRange('A1:H45'); 
var data = range.getValues();

var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("prevMonth");

if (yourNewSheet != null) 
{
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
}

yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
yourNewSheet.setName("prevMonth");
yourNewSheet.getRange(yourNewSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,45,8).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Hey @ZilSanghvi I have provided an answer. Please let me know if that's what you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 I tried your code, its working and returning current month name, but i want previous month name.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot the most important part of the question. Please see the revised version of my answer. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 Thank you so much, its working now !!!

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 Kindly help me with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948993/copy-format-with-the-range-of-values-from-the-google-sheet-file

Answer (score 1):

By using the code below:

```js
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT'); 
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:H45'); 
  var data = range.getValues();
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
  var prevMonth = Utilities.formatDate(d, 'GMT+1', 'MMMM yyyy');

  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(prevMonth);

  if (yourNewSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
  }

  yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  yourNewSheet.setName(prevMonth);
  yourNewSheet.getRange(yourNewSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,45,8).setValues(data);
}
```

It will create a Sheet named  "October 2019".