# Copy format with the range of values from the google sheet file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have used the following code, It is doing following actions :
-> Autocreating the new google sheet, Copying the data of the required columns, Renaming it to the previous month name.

```
function Copy() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40'); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A1:H45'); //assign the range you want to copy
var data = range.getValues();
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
var prevMonth = Utilities.formatDate(d, 'GMT+1','MMMM-yyyy'); //rename sheet to previous month

var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(prevMonth);

if (yourNewSheet != null) {
    activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
}
yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
yourNewSheet.setName(prevMonth);
yourNewSheet.getRange(yourNewSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,45,8).setValues(data);
}
```

Only thing missing is that , its not copying the original format from which it is copied. Format is getting changed like line number, duration etc. Here are screenshots of original and new file.

This is Orginal,
[image]

And this is copied one.
[image]

Comment: Hey Zil, I have published an answer - although what it does is quite different from your original code. Let me know if that's the behaviour you are looking for. Cheers

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 The code you wrote below is working fine, got everything with same format but problem is i used getRange , getValues, setValues and all because i just want values, i dont want excel cell formula to be copied in my backup file. I want to fetch values only but with format. Please help me wiith that,

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you may be overcomplicating a few things in your original code. If what you want is to copy a sheet (with **all** of its contents and formatting) into another Spreadsheet, you can simply use the `sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet)` function. This way, you will not even need to work with the `Range`'s. You have to refactor the code as follows:

```js
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT');

  var d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
  var prevMonth = Utilities.formatDate(d, 'GMT+1', 'MMMM yyyy');
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Check whether "sheet backup" already exists for that month
  if (activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(prevMonth) !== null) return;

  var yourNewSheet = ss.copyTo(activeSpreadsheet);
  yourNewSheet.setName(prevMonth);
}
```

### Edit

In order to "materialise" the formulas (copy its values to the spreadsheet, rather than the formulas themselves) you can do the following:

After copying the sheet (using `copyTo()` as previously explained), you simply overwrite the contents using `getValues()` in the original sheet and `setValues()` in the destination sheet. Your final code would look like the following:

```js
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1IK6YsZS3_NNAlFA41d8uKriPzfZs_2Ukyh94eeBFj40');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('CURRENT');

  var d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
  var prevMonth = Utilities.formatDate(d, 'GMT+1', 'MMMM yyyy');
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Check whether "sheet backup" already exists for that month
  if (activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(prevMonth) !== null) return;

  var yourNewSheet = ss.copyTo(activeSpreadsheet);
  yourNewSheet.setName(prevMonth);

  var dataValues = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // NEW
  yourNewSheet.getDataRange().setValues(dataValues); // NEW
}
```

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 The code you wrote below is working fine, got everything with same format but problem is i used getRange , getValues, setValues and all because i just want values, i dont want excel cell formula to be copied in my backup file. I want to fetch values only but with format. Please help me wiith that, –

Comment: @ZilSanghvi Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I have edited my answer, kindly let me know if that works for you. Cheers

Comment: Code is running successfully but no result obtained. Nothing happening.

Comment: @ZilSanghvi Kindly try removing any sheet that was created by this script (name in the format 'month year') and try running it again. Do you obtain any results now?

Comment: @ZilSanghvi that is weird, since I only added some lines of code. It should, at minimum, behave like the previous function. Could you check within the Apps Script IDE, in View>Logs>Apps Script Dashboard whether there are any "failed" executions? Are there any logs in there? Thanks!

Comment: @carlessgg97  modified the code too,as error was coming on getSheetBy in your code ,that it is undefined . Kindly check if correct as no results coming.                                                                   
just moved this line  below Utilities.format line                                                                                       
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

Comment: @carelessgg97 checked executions. Its showing complete.My first code which i posted in question is working.

Comment: @ZilSanghvi thanks for your comment, it was the activeSheet declaration. I edited my answer to reflect the change. Is it working as you intend now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202910/discussion-between-zil-sanghvi-and-carlesgg97).